# SecondarySort -OverrideError(Remove annotation)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

The error it points in eclipse is that I have to remove annotation override. Even though I tried to remove annotation,again error exits it says that the method has to re implemented

.................................................................
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

```
package com.secondarysort;
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils;

/**
 * @author mrinmoy
 *
 */
public class CompositeKey implements WritableComparable
{
    public String Text;
    public String count;

    public CompositeKey (String Text,String count)
    {
        this.Text=Text;
        this.count=count;
    }

    public CompositeKey() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getText() {
        return Text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        Text = text;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return (new StringBuilder()).append(Text).append(',').append(count).toString();
    }



    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Text = WritableUtils.readString(arg0);
        count=WritableUtils.readString(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WritableUtils.writeString(arg0,Text);
        WritableUtils.writeString(arg0, count);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(CompositeKey com) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int result=Text.compareTo(com.Text);
        if(0==result)
        {
            result=count.compareTo(com.count);
        }
        return result;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the generic type of `WritableComparable` you are overriding, otherwise you're not overriding `compareTo` correctly. This is because the compiler substitutes no generics for `Object`, so a `compareTo` taking only `CompositeKey`s does not override it. Change it to:

```
public class CompositeKey implements WritableComparable<CompositeKey> {
    // ...
}
```